# SQL Data Type function parameter when writing function to create a stored procedure parameter

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, ado.net

I'm currently writing a function that will make it easier to add parameters to stored procedures programmatically, but so far the only stumbling block I'm having is adding the data type in as a function parameter. The code is:

```
Public Shared Function spParamAdd(cmd As SqlCommand, paramName As String, dataType As SqlDbType, value As String)
    Dim command = cmd.Parameters.Add(paramName, SqlDbType.dataType).Value = value
    Return command
End Function
```

And the code I'm trying to derive this from is:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@USERID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1
```

Finally, the error I'm getting is:

> dataType is not a member of System.Data.SqlDbType

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Your using sqldatatype wrong...

Comment: What's the correct way to use it?

Comment: You can probably try.. .Add(paramName, dataType) since you are passing it in through your function.

Comment: Just a minute, I give you solution...

Comment: please see my answer I have provided for you. Very easy to add params to your command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it took some time, here's a great solution for you... **This code is tried and tested**
This will add parameter's to your command object easily if your looking for a way to add them...

**Method to add parameters to a command object**

As you can see below, we only need the command object (ByRef) so we can directly use it, your parameter name itself, the data type and finally the value. Also there's a select case as we need to know exactly what data type we are dealing with so we can cast our value to the correct type...

```
 Public Shared Sub spParamAdd(ByRef cmd As SqlCommand, ByVal paramName As String, ByVal dataType As SqlDbType, ByVal value As Object)
    'Need to make sure we have the correct datatype, add more as needed!
    Select Case dataType
        Case SqlDbType.VarChar
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, CStr(value)).DbType = dataType
        Case SqlDbType.Int
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, CInt(value)).DbType = dataType
    End Select

End Sub
```

**Example Useage**

```
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
 spParamAdd(cmd, "@Customer_ID", SqlDbType.Int, 12)
 spParamAdd(cmd, "@Last_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, "Dickins")
```

**Another Example - Not really suggested...**
You can also omit the select case **BUT** you better make sure your value you send in and the data type is the same!

```
 Public Shared Sub spParamAdd(ByRef cmd As SqlCommand, ByVal paramName As String, ByVal dataType As SqlDbType, ByVal value As Object)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, value).DbType = dataType
End Sub
```

Let me know how this works out for you!

Happy Coding!